# Push to GitHub from CircleCI with Deploy Key (R/W), but GitHub says the key is read-only

Tags: github, ssh, circleci

(Note: I know that a personal access token will work, but external reasons require me to do this via an SSH Deploy Key. Both the source repo and the target repo are private.)

I need to use CircleCI to push every commit from the source repo to the target repo. Assume the repos are named `source` and `target`. I am configuring CircleCI to run my custom push script but it's saying that the key is read-only.

What I've done:

- Created a new key pair with `ssh-keygen` on my PC and compress the private key.
- Uploaded the public key `id_rsa.pub` to the target repo as a Deploy Key, with "allow push access with this key" ticked.
- Put the compressed private key in the repository Environment Variables on CircleCI
- Wrote this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [ -z "$SSH_KEY_E" ]; then
  echo "No SSH key found in environment, set it as \$SSH_KEY_E" >&2
  exit 1
fi

echo "$SSH_KEY_E" |
  base64 -d |
  gunzip -c > ~/.ssh/m.id_rsa

set -x # debug

cat >> ~/.ssh/config << EOF
Host GHMirror
  HostName github.com
  User git
  Port 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/m.id_rsa
EOF
git remote add mirror GHMirror:iBug/circleci-target.git
git push mirror +master
```

The output log indicates that the key restored from environment is valid, but it doesn't seem like it's used to push to GitHub.

Some points I'd like to point out:

- At the beginning, I overwrote `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and used directly `git@github.com:iBug/target.git` as the remote URL for `mirror`, but it didn't work, saying the key is read-only
- Then, thinking that the default key (by CircleCI) might be located at somewhere else, I changed the remote host to `GHMirror` and wrote this rule to `~/.ssh/config`, as seen in the shell script. Still it complains that the key is read-only
- I changed the key to another path `~/.ssh/m.id_rsa`, but no luck.

I have verified that everything by running the script locally, and it successfully pushed to the target repository, so there must be something on CircleCI that I'm missing.

#### Update 1

I added the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv"` and got this result:

```
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
...
debug2: key:  (0xREDACTED), agent
debug2: key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/circleci/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
```

However, `ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa` shows that the file *is* there, with permission 0600.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but don't you need `--push` when adding the remote?

Comment: @Drazisil Doesn't specifying this new remote in `git push mirror +master` work? Note that here `mirror` is the name of the newly added remote, not the option `--mirror`.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of `git remote set-url` I'll let others better versed in git answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is due to the ssh-agent offering the CircleCI key, which is read-only. I've hit this problem as well in the past. To debug you can use the following:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv"
```

This will print out details about which key is being used.

I was able to fix the problem with something like this:

```
# Disable the ssh-agent
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=none
# Tell ssh to use the specific SSH key 
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i path/to/key"
```

Also make sure that you `chmod 0600 path/to/key`. SSH will not use keys if they are readable by other users.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case for me. I'll update my question. But the strange thing is, your solution is working, even if I can't figure out whether your reasoning is correct (the log shows that `ssh` can't find the key, not that ssh-agent offering something wrong).